# How hard is it to remove a European-style rear-wheel ring lock?

Tags: lock, modification, wheel-lock

I have an old Breezer Uptown 8 with a European-style ring lock on the rear wheel. I am thinking of removing it. Does anyone have experience doing this? Is it as easy as unscrewing a bolt? It looks like maybe it is bolted on with the fender mount.

I am worried that this may be very difficult because if it was not, the lock would not be very useful.

Comment: This type of lock is to stop somebody from riding away on you bike. Even if they unscrewed the bolt, they would still be unable to ride away as it would still be around the tire, and it would stop the wheel from turning at some point as it wouldn't be able to fit through the seat stays or chainstays as the wheel turned, and even if it could it could cause constant bumping as the rider rode over it.  That being said, these locks are quite low security, as they don't stop the person from carrying your bike away, but in some situations that's all you need.

Comment: I believe these locks are called cafe locks some places.

Answer (score 6):

Performed the operation today and it was, as suggested, very easy. Simply unscrewed a bolt on each side affixing the lock to the seat stays. For mine, the lock did not obstruct these bolts. I was then able to twist the ring lock and pull off the wheel, around the fenders, without any more fuss.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted an answer, so that this doesn't float back to the front page.

Comment: Great work - Thank you for posting a closure answer.   Do hit the little green tick/check button on the left to accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you can unlock it, it's very easy as the mounting bolts are uncovered when it's unlocked.

If it is locked, then it's a bit more difficult but not much more. The lock housing you can see in the image below is just stamped metal riveted together. Some ring locks are so weak that a good whack on the locking lever will spring it open.  Otherwise, the easiest way to remove it is the same way thieves would do it: use an angle grinder or bolt cutters. It takes about 10-20 seconds with the right tools.

[image]

Because ring locks only lock the rear wheel to the frame, they are very low security. They're fine for low-theft environments and for heavy steel utility bikes or mommy-bikes, but if you have a nice, light bike, it's easy for thief to just pick up the bike and throw it over their shoulder or throw it in a truck. Essentially, ring locks keep people honest in honest communities.

Source: I've lived in Japan for several years where ring locks are the main style used, and had to replace locks for family members who have lost keys.

Answer (score 2):

If it's like the one I've used, when the lock is unlocked you only need to remove 2 bolts. They're covered when the lock goes through the wheel (actually i think only 1 of them is but I'm not near the bike now). I don't think the mudguard is affected by taking the lock off but of course yours may be different and you may need to improvise something. In the end you'll just have to try it and see but you could add some pictures if you're worried.